# Is there a 64-bit version of Groovy for Windows 10?

Tags: 64-bit, java, jvm, groovy

Is there a 64-bit version of Groovy? My OS is Windows 10.

I have been looking for days with no luck. The problem I have is that I need to use a 64-bit JVM with Groovy so that I can maximize the JVM heap size (I need more than 4G which is the maximum heap size when using 32-bit JVM).

Comment: [This](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7788) seems to indicate a 64-bit version already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the groovy-windows-installer walk-through guide on [GitHub](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-windows-installer/wiki/Usage-Guide), it states that:

> The installer detects whether the Java on the path is 32 bit or 64 bit
>   and installs the appropriate executable and advises the user the
>   detected endianness.

[image]

You can download the installer from [Apache Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html)
or access some older versions on [Bintray](https://bintray.com/groovy/Distributions/Windows-Installer/view).